# Skip publication signing if signing properties are not defined

Tags: groovy, android-gradle-plugin, jitpack, android-app-signing

I have forked an android library on github, applied some fixes to it and now would like to get a snapshot version as a dependency to my own project, but the build task in jitpack.io fails

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':project_name:signReleasePublication'.
> path may not be null or empty string. path=''
```

The project has `publish-mavencentral.gradle` script setup for publishing task with signing properties read from a file or envirnment variables which I guess is causing the issue

```
ext["signing.keyId"] = ''
ext["signing.password"] = ''
ext["signing.secretKeyRingFile"] = ''
ext["ossrhUsername"] = ''
ext["ossrhPassword"] = ''
ext["sonatypeStagingProfileId"] = ''

File secretPropsFile = project.rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (secretPropsFile.exists()) {
    Properties p = new Properties()
    p.load(new FileInputStream(secretPropsFile))
    p.each { name, value ->
        ext[name] = value
    }
} else {
    ext["signing.keyId"] = System.getenv('SIGNING_KEY_ID')
    ext["signing.password"] = System.getenv('SIGNING_PASSWORD')
    ext["signing.secretKeyRingFile"] = System.getenv('SIGNING_SECRET_KEY_RING_FILE')
    ext["ossrhUsername"] = System.getenv('OSSRH_USERNAME')
    ext["ossrhPassword"] = System.getenv('OSSRH_PASSWORD')
    ext["sonatypeStagingProfileId"] = System.getenv('SONATYPE_STAGING_PROFILE_ID')
}

signing {
    sign publishing.publications
}
```

Tried adding the `required()` directive, but it did not work

```
signing {
    required { hasProperty("signing.keyId") }
    sign publishing.publications
}
```

How to skip signing if the properties are empty?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in the key composite name. Renamed `signing.keyId` to `signingKeyId` and `required()` started to work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Use the project scope of hasProperty().

```
signing {
    required { project.hasProperty("signing.keyId") }
    sign publishing.publications
}
```